# MSBUILD - Como publicar vários projetos de uma unica Solution (OSGI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, compilação

estou precisando de uma ajuda para publicar meus projetos.
Estou utilizando OSGI para modular minha aplicação, com consequência na minha solution existe varias aplicações WEB.

> Ex: Solution A
>
> ```
>  1. Aplicação 1
>  2. Aplicação 2
>  3. Aplicação 3
>  4. Aplicação Principal
> ```

Essas aplicações não tem nenhum referencia entre si, mas preciso que todas as aplicações fiquem dentro de um pasta ("Plugins") dentro da Rais da "Aplicação Pai" na hora da publicação.

Obs. Preciso dessas aplicações com todos os arquivos necessários (Views, Script ... Etc, ) não pode ser só o binário pois são aplicações Web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode tentar via linha de comando:

```
msbuild example.sln /p:Configuration=Test;DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=Test.example.pubxml /MaxCpuCount:8
```

A ideia é criar um bach (bat) para fazer esta publicação. O bacana é que se em algum projeto você mudar alguma configuração de publicação (arquivo .pubxml), isto irá refletir no bat.